# HTML Email Invite sent to outlook does not show border

Tags: outlook, html-table, salesforce, border, html-email

I am sending a email invite from apex class. The email body is a HTML Body with a table in it.

The borders of the table are not visible in email invite sent. I am viewing the invite from outlook.

I tried send the following different HTML code as body but none work:

1. `<table border="1">`
2. `<table style="border:1px solid black;">`
3. style tag with border to each td, tr .

Please help to have border visible in the **email invite** sent.

Answer (score 0):

Appointment items don't have the HTML body. They use RTF for bodies.

Anyway, Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)